# Passing type bound procedures as arguments

Tags: function, fortran, user-defined-types, fortran2003

I am trying to pass a type bound procedure as an argument to another subroutine. I want to know if this is possible in Fortran. Here is a code snippet that shows what I am trying to do .

```
module type_definitions 
 type test_type 
 integer :: i1, i2,i3
 contains 
   procedure :: add_integers_up 
 end type test_type
 contains 
   subroutine add_integers_up(this,i4,ans)
       class(test_type) :: this 
       integer :: i4,ans 
       ans = this%i1+this%i2+this%i3+i4
    end subroutine add_integers_up

subroutine print_result_of_subroutine(i4,random_subroutine) 
  integer :: i4,ans 

  interface 
     subroutine  random_subroutine(i1,i2) 
       integer:: i1,i2
     end subroutine random_subroutine
  end interface

  call random_subroutine(i4,ans) 
  write(*,*) ans 


end subroutine print_result_of_subroutine


end module type_definitions


program main 
   use type_definitions
   implicit none 
   integer :: i1,i2,i3,i4
   integer :: ans 
   type(test_type) :: test_obj

   i1 =1; i2=2; i3=3
   test_obj%i1 = i1 
   test_obj%i2 = i2 
   test_obj%i3 = i3 
   i4 = 4

   call print_result_of_subroutine(i4,test_obj%add_integers_up) 

    end program main
```

Is this possible to do in Fortran? I get a compiler error when I try to compile this code using ifort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

test_obj%add_integers_up is not a procedure - it is a binding that happens to be to a procedure called add_integers_up.  You cannot pass a binding as an actual argument.

If you want to pass the specific procedure that the binding is associated with, then pass the procedure!  Hypothetically:

```
call print_result_of_subroutine(i4, add_integers_up)
```

But as other posters have noted, in your example code the interface of that procedure does not match the interface of the corresponding dummy argument in print_result_of_subroutine.

If test_obj%add_integers_up referred to an associated procedure pointer component (and the interface for that component matched what was being expected by the print_result_of_subroutine) then things would work as you appear to be expecting.

Note that Fortran 90 does not support type bound procedures (or procedure pointer components) - your code very much requires Fortran 2003.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't show us the exact error message you got, and I didn't try your example myself, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that the interface of the procedure dummy argument doesn't correspond to the interface of the actual argument that is passed to it.

More explicitly, `random_subroutine` is declared as taking two arguments, while `test_obj%add_integers_up` takes three arguments; even though one of them functions as the passed-object dummy argument, it still counts as part of the interface of that procedure.

Comment: Exactly! I can only add that I would use 'procedure' or 'module procedure' in the interface block and avoid specifying the interface directly.