# Type bound procedure as arguments

Tags: fortran, procedures, derived-types

I want to pass a type bound procedures (as an external function) to another function as follows:

```
module mod1
   implicit none

   type type1
      real :: a
      contains
      procedure,pass :: f
   end type

contains

   real function f(y,e)
      class(type1), intent(in) :: y
      real,intent(in) :: e
      f=y%a+e
   end function

end module

program test

   use mod1
   type(type1) :: t

   t%a=3e0
   write(*,*) s(t%f)

contains

   real function s(g)
      real,external :: g
      s=g(5e0)+2e0
   end function

end program
```

gfortran produces gives this error :

```
       write(*,*) s(t%f)
                       1
Error: Expected argument list at (1)
```

But what I can do is:

```
program test

   t%a=3e0
   write(*,*) s(k)

contains

   real function s(g)
      real,external :: g
      s=g(5e0)+2e0
   end function

   real function k(e)
      real,intent(in) :: e
      k=3e0+e
   end function

end program
```

I think the problem is related to [Passing type bound procedures as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318816/passing-type-bound-procedures-as-arguments-in-fortran-90), but I don't see at the moment how the answers there can help me.

EDIT:

A better example which (hopefully) shows the difficulty:

```
module mod2
   implicit none
contains

   real function s(g)
       interface
        real function g(x)
          real, intent(in) :: x
        end function
      end interface

      s=g(5e0)+2e0
   end function
end module

module mod1
   use mod2

   type type1
      real :: a
      contains
      procedure,pass :: f
      procedure,pass :: h
   end type

contains

   real function f(y,e)
      class(type1), intent(in) :: y
      real,intent(in) :: e
      f=y%a+e
   end function

   real function h(y)
      class(type1), intent(inout) :: y
      h=s(y%f)
   end function
end module

program test

use mod1
   type(type1) :: t

   t%a=3e0
   write(*,*) t%h
end program
```

EDIT II:
Ok, the wrappers still work in combination with a pointer:

```
module mod2
   implicit none
contains

   real function s(g)
       interface
        real function g(x)
          real, intent(in) :: x
        end function
      end interface

      s=g(5e0)+2e0
   end function
end module 

module mod1 
   use mod2

   type type1
      real :: a
      contains
      procedure,pass :: f
      procedure,pass :: h
   end type

   class(type1),pointer :: help_w

contains

   real function f(y,e)
      class(type1), intent(in) :: y
      real,intent(in) :: e
      f=y%a+e
   end function

   real function h(y)
      class(type1), intent(inout),target :: y
      help_w => y
      h=s(wrap) 
   end function

   function wrap(x)
      real,intent(in) :: x
      wrap=help_w%f(x)
   end function 
end module

program test

use mod1
   type(type1) :: t

   t%a=3e0
   write(*,*) t%h()
end program
```

This is certainly not a beautiful solution but at least it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a wrapper. This is the most straightforward version. Requires passing internal function as a dummy argument (F2008), but you could declare the wrapper in a module too, if the `t` can bee there.

Note I changed the declaration of the procedure argument in `s` to something more modern - the interface block.

```
program test
   use mod1
   type(type1) :: t

   t%a=3e0
   write(*,*) s(wrap)

contains

   real function s(g)
      interface
        real function g(x)
          real, intent(in) :: x
        end function
      end interface

      s=g(5e0)+2e0
   end function

   function wrap(x)
     real, intent(in) :: x
     wrap = t%f(x)
   end function

end program
```

The reason for your error is well described in the answers to the linked question, you cannot pass type bound procedures the way you tried.

Comment: Yes, I see that I oversimplified my example. Sorry! I'll add another version where I don't see how I can define a wrapper in such an easy way, since it isn't declared when I define the calling. Hope this shows the difficulty better.

Comment: Yeah, with an aditional pointer it again work. So thanks a lot.